# PHP sessions in Redis with login and prefix - separate user for each website

Tags: php, session, redis

I want to store PHP sessions in Redis. However, since this is shared hosting, I need to have own Redis user for each site, with rights only to their own data.

I followed the instructions: https://github.com/phpredis/phpredis#php-session-handler, https://github.com/phpredis/phpredis/issues/1879

My configuration:

`/etc/redis/redis.conf`.

```
include /etc/redis/users.d/*.conf
user default on >test ~* &* +@all
```

`/etc/redis/users.d/web1.conf`:

```
user web1 on >hello ~web1* +@all
```

`/etc/php/8.1/fpm/pool.d/web1.conf`:

```
php_value[session.save_handler] = redis
php_value[session.save_path] = "tcp://127.0.0.1:6379?auth[username]=web1&auth[password]=web1&prefix=web1_PHPREDIS_SESSION:"
php_value[session.cookie_lifetime] = 172800
php_value[session.gc_maxlifetime] = 172800
```

`test.php`:

```
<?php
ini_set('display_errors', 1);
session_start(['read_and_close' => true]);
$_SESSION['hello'] = 'world';
echo $_SESSION['hello'];
die();
```

`AUTH`, `SET` and `GET` in via `redis-cli` works. But after testing with the PHP script, nothing is saved to Redis.

Redis 7.0.10, PHP 8.1, Debian 11.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: After changing `session.save_path` to `"seed[]=tcp://127.0.0.1:6379?auth[username]=web1&auth[password]=web1&prefix=web1_PHPREDIS_SESSION:"` (added `seed[]=`) it works, but I don't know why.

Comment: With the `seed[]=` prefix, the script does not fail, but nothing is saved to redis :-(